# Submit button enable and disable in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm a beginner in coding, want to enable and disable a form once the form got filled. So in my thought
I was checking if the validation array is empty it should enable the button else disable this is what I tried. In computed I was checking array is null but disabling the button not able to enable it. Please let me know the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form 
            @submit.prevent="submitRegistration(); accesTimercount()" 
            v-show="!bakeryRegSuccessMsg"
        >
            <h3>Sign Up Your Bakery with Us</h3>
            <div class="row gtr-uniform">
                <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="bakeryName" 
                        value 
                        placeholder="Bakery Name" 
                        v-model="bakeryname" 
                        autocomplete="off" 
                        required 
                    />
                    <span class="errNotific" v-if="validation.bakeryname">{{validation.bakeryname}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="ownerName" 
                        value placeholder="Owner's Name" 
                        v-model="ownername" 
                        autocomplete="off" 
                        required 
                    />
                    <span class="errNotific" v-if="validation.ownername">{{validation.ownername}}</span>
                </div>   
                <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                    <textarea 
                        class="boxBorder" 
                        name="description" 
                        placeholder="Write a short description about your Bakery" 
                        rows="3" 
                        v-model="description" 
                        required
                    ></textarea>
                    <span class="errNotific" v-if="validation.description">{{validation.description}}</span>
                </div>                      
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="primary" :disabled="btndisable"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            bakeryname: "",
            ownername: "",
            description: "",
            validation: [],
        }
    },

    computed: {
        btndisable: function() {
            return this.validation.length === 0 ? true : false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        // select box getting locations and towns
 
        // API call for Submitting bakery registration

        // form validation call
        
        check_bakeryname(value) {
            if (value == "") {
                this.validation["bakeryname"] = "Enter your bakery name";
            } else {
                this.validation["bakeryname"] = "";
            }
        },
        check_ownername(value) {
            if (value == "") {
                this.validation["ownername"] = "Enter bakery owner's name";
            } else {
                this.validation["ownername"] = "";
            }
        },    
        check_description(value) {
            if (value == "") {
                this.validation["description"] = "please fill the description ";
            } else {
                this.validation["description"] = "";
            }
        }
    },
  
    watch: {
        bakeryname(value) {
            this.bakeryname = value;
            this.check_bakeryname(value);
        },
        ownername(value) {
            this.ownername = value;
            this.check_ownername(value);
        },
        description(value) {
            this.description = value;
            this.check_description(value);
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Your component is treating `validation` sometimes like an array (defining it as `[]`, and checking `.length`) and sometimes like an object (setting `description` property).  First you'll need to get that sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you initialize `validation` to an empty array: `validation = []`, then later you use bracket notation to initialize its properties like this:

```
this.validation["bakeryname"] = "Enter your bakery name"
```

so the new `validation` object is created, which is totally different to `validation` array at the beginning. They are two different types, just like a variable named `example` will be different to a function named `example`.

Please check the quick example here I created to demonstrate your issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kienht/z6qy71dk/5/

Another thing is, the operator here should be `!==` not `===`, because you want to return `false` if your `validation` array is empty, so the user will be able to click the button

```
btndisable: function() {
    return this.validation.length !== 0
}
```

**EDIT**

That just helps answer your question to find where the problem is, not the solution. Instead of having 3 different methods for checking validation, you could just need to return a boolean like below, and you don't have to use `watch` because you use `v-model`, your values will be dynamically updated as well as your computed property. I could you go simple like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            bakeryname: "",
            ownername: "",
            description: "",
        }
    },

    computed: {
        btndisable: function() {
            return (!bakeryname || !ownername || !description)
        }
    },
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.so in my case i have to make my validation array like validation:[bakeryName:""] with all v-models

Comment: @mayaj I have editted my answer, please have a look

Comment: @KeinHT,Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation,worked for me